# Facade Error - Non-static method should not be called statically

Tags: php, laravel-5, shopify

I want to create an shopify app with laravel.I am using the package  https://packagist.org/packages/bnmetrics/laravel-shopify-api

I have followed all the steps shown there.But after running this app I am getting this error

```
Non-static method BNMetrics\Shopify\Shopify::make() should not be called statically
```

I have already registered service provider and add shopify facade as instructed.But the issue exist.Is there anything I am missing?

I am newbie to laravel and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: i am assuming you have some method/ function defined as function myFunction() {}  and using it by self::myFunction().  this is giving the deprecated warning.  create object of your class and then call the function
like $obj = new self();
$obj->myFunction();
this would solve your warning issue

Comment: Hey @Gunnrryy, thanks for your suggestion.But creating the object of the desired class is little bit complex.So the package doc suggest to use the facade.Are there any solution if I stick with doc's instruction?

Comment: i dont see any issue as such, but are you having any issue with it?  please understand that warnings are different and errors are different. you can ignore notices, may ignore warning, and have to re-solve the errors. what is your issue, specify that.  you might want to try error_reporting(^E_WARNING );

Comment: Solved the issue.Cheers! I have misunderstood to use facade in laravel.I should follow the sequence of instruction to use facade.And thank you for your concern.Obviously I will check the difference among error, warning and   
notices.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I had the same problem and I realized that I was importing

> use BNMetrics\Shopify\Shopify;

and I just needed to import

> use Shopify;

just in case it helps someone else